# How to make a generic struct as function parameter

Tags: rust

I tried to write a function that takes a generic struct as a parameter:

```rust
struct S<T> {
    v: T,
}

fn foo(a: &S) {
    a.v
}
```

But an error occurs:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:5:12
  |
5 | fn foo(a: &S) {
  |            ^ expected 1 type argument

error: aborting due to previous error
```

---

## First update

After changing to

```rust
struct S<T> {
    v: T,
}

fn foo<T>(a: &S<T>) -> T {
    a.v
}
```

Another error occurs:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a.v` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     a.v
  |     ^^^ move occurs because `a.v` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

---

## Second update

Finally, I got what I want:

```rust
struct S<T> {
    v: T,
}

fn foo<T: Copy>(a: &S<T>) -> T {
    a.v
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the generic parameter

```
struct S<T> {
    v: T,
}

fn foo<T>(a: S<T>) -> T {
    a.v
}

Or use the Copy bound

fn foo<T: Copy>(a: &S<T>) -> T {
  a.v
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After changing my code, there is still an error. I updated my question.

Comment: You can use `a: S<T>` instead

Comment: But I want `a` will not be dropped after calling `foo`. Would you mind looking at my last update?

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a nice day.